# Unable to Retrieve the Data Extension Fields using Soap Api

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions

I have to Retrieve the Data Extension Fields from Data Extension object using Soap Api,But I am unable to Retrieve the Data Extension fields using Data Extension Object.

Data Extension Soap Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:par="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <UsernameToken>
        <Username>xxxxxx</Username>
        <Password>xxxxxxx</Password>
      </UsernameToken>
    </Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
        <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
        <Properties>Name</Properties>
        <Properties>DataExtension.ObjectID</Properties>
        <Properties>IsSendable</Properties>
        <Properties>SendableSubscriberField.Name</Properties>
        <Properties>SendableDataExtensionField.Name</Properties>
        <Properties>Fields</Properties>
        <Property>Field.CustomerKey</Property>
        <Property>Field.FieldType</Property>
        <Properties>CategoryID</Properties>
        <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
          <Property>CategoryID</Property>
          <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
          <Value>xxxxxx</Value>
        </Filter>
        <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
      </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here I am trying to Retrieve the fields , but i am unable to Retrieve, what i have to give the value?

```
<Properties>Fields</Properties>
 <Property>Field.CustomerKey</Property>
 <Property>Field.FieldType</Property>
```

I dont want to use DataExtension Field object,I want to Retrieve the fields using Data Extension object,please anyone help me for the Answer...

> Error Message:

```
 <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <OverallStatus>Error: The Request Property(s) Fields do not match with the fields of DataExtension retrieve</OverallStatus>
         <RequestID>3aadeb4f-2290-402d-9590-f0f07ac3247f</RequestID>
      </RetrieveResponseMsg>
```

Comment: Please update your question with the exact error message you are getting when you execute your code.

Comment: I have update the Error Message @AdamSpriggs

Answer (score 5):

You have to do a retrieve on the `DataExtensionField` object, specifying the `DataExtension.CustomerKey` in your filter:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <!-- header removed -->
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <RetrieveRequest>
        <ClientIDs>
          <ID>999999999</ID>
        </ClientIDs>
        <ObjectType>DataExtensionField</ObjectType>
        <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
        <Properties>PartnerKey</Properties>
        <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
        <Properties>Name</Properties>
        <Properties>DefaultValue</Properties>
        <Properties>MaxLength</Properties>
        <Properties>IsRequired</Properties>
        <Properties>Ordinal</Properties>
        <Properties>IsPrimaryKey</Properties>
        <Properties>FieldType</Properties>
        <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>Scale</Properties>
        <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
        <Properties>DataExtension.CustomerKey</Properties>
        <Properties>StorageType</Properties>
        <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
          <Property>DataExtension.CustomerKey</Property>
          <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
          <Value>DATAEXTENSIONCUSTOMERKEY</Value>
        </Filter>
      </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**Reference**

- [**DataExtensionField Object**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextensionfield.htm)

Comment: I know this already, i want to retrieve fields using  <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType> @Adam Spriggs

Comment: please Guide me for this Scenario

Comment: The field information is in a separate object -- `DataExtensionField` -- not `DataExtension`.  The `DataExtension.CustomerKey` exists in `DataExtension`, so if you don't know it, you'll need to retrieve that first.