# Get all fields in DE via API or Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit

Is there any chance i can retrive the names of all fields with created date in a data extension via Query/API

Answer (score 4):

As provide in the example on this question ['Retrieve the Data Extension Fields using Soap Api'](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192355/unable-to-retrieve-the-data-extension-fields-using-soap-api)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <fueloauth>XXXXXXXXXXXX</fueloauth>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>DataExtensionField</ObjectType>
            <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
            <Properties>PartnerKey</Properties>
            <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
            <Properties>Name</Properties>
            <Properties>DefaultValue</Properties>
            <Properties>MaxLength</Properties>
            <Properties>IsRequired</Properties>
            <Properties>Ordinal</Properties>
            <Properties>IsPrimaryKey</Properties>
            <Properties>FieldType</Properties>
            <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>Scale</Properties>
            <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
            <Properties>DataExtension.CustomerKey</Properties>
            <Properties>StorageType</Properties>
         <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
          <Property>DataExtension.CustomerKey</Property>
          <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
          <Value>XXXXXXXX</Value>
        </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```