# How to deploy data extension between SFMC orgs without putting all fields manually

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, marketingcloudapi, postman

I know that a Data extension could beb deployed using tool like Postman through API by SOAP request as described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_data_extension_using_web_service_api.htm)
 But this request requires adding all the fields to the request manually. How can this be avoided? Is there a way to include all fields (like using * or something) so that this manual effort is removed? Or is there a way to get all fields of data extension in same format as required in the SOAP request?

We can [retrieve Data extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_data_from_a_data_extension.htm) using the API call which has all the fields, but again the fields needs to be copy pasted from this response to Deploy request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the June release, [Deployment Manager](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_june_2019_platform_deployment_manager_data_extensions.htm&type=5) can achieve this for you.

But this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192355/unable-to-retrieve-the-data-extension-fields-using-soap-api) shows you retrieve all the fields in the DE

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <!-- header removed -->
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <RetrieveRequest>
        <ClientIDs>
          <ID>999999999</ID>
        </ClientIDs>
        <ObjectType>DataExtensionField</ObjectType>
        <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
        <Properties>PartnerKey</Properties>
        <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
        <Properties>Name</Properties>
        <Properties>DefaultValue</Properties>
        <Properties>MaxLength</Properties>
        <Properties>IsRequired</Properties>
        <Properties>Ordinal</Properties>
        <Properties>IsPrimaryKey</Properties>
        <Properties>FieldType</Properties>
        <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>Scale</Properties>
        <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
        <Properties>DataExtension.CustomerKey</Properties>
        <Properties>StorageType</Properties>
        <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
          <Property>DataExtension.CustomerKey</Property>
          <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
          <Value>DATAEXTENSIONCUSTOMERKEY</Value>
        </Filter>
      </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```